# When a word's synonym is the same as its plural: how do you name lists and instances?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

The word `species` is singular and plural at the same time.

What is the best practice in a case like this to name the variables that involve many species and one single species?

eg 1:

```
 List<Species> species = new List<Species>(); // Many species
 Species species = new Species(); // A species (problem)
```

eg 2:

```
 foreach (Species species in species) // Problem
 {
 }
```

Comment: Regarding the downvote: I don't agree that this is a "primarily opinion-based" question, because you can evaluate the quality of the answers on its facts rather than opinions.

Comment: This is probably better suited for the Programmers Stack Exchange. There are other questions like this on StackOverflow though. Here's a relevant meta discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97640/should-programming-best-practices-be-on-stackoverflow-or-programmers-se

Comment: "There are other questions like this on StackOverflow though", I'm not following you: Are you suggesting this question is a duplicate or are you just downrating your first opinion ("this is probably better suited for Programmers SE")?

Comment: You might get downvotes and close votes when asking about best practices on here, even though there are questions that ask for best practices on this site. Some people think they are off topic or opinion-based. Programmers SE will probably be more receptive to this type of question, but you got an answer so I wouldn't worry about it too much!

Comment: This is really a style question.  You could name them `foo` and `bar` and it would work.  Therefore I think it solidly lands in Primarily Opinion-Based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different nouns for what you're representing at a given time.  It may sound close to Hungarian notation, but consider the difference:

```
List<Species> speciesList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Species species : speciesList) {
    // iteration operations
}
```

Suffixing `speciesList` with `List` indicates that there's zero or more species being referenced by this variable at any one given time.